# Java Calendar instance increments DAY_OF_MONTH as a side effect of decrementing (only) HOUR or MINUTE

Tags: java, android, date, datetime, calendar

I have [an unfinished Android app](https://gitlab.com/n8chz/shit/) with a main activity with a `TimePicker` (`@+id/tyme`), a `DatePicker` (`@+id/date`), and a `TextView` (`@+id/dropTime`) for displaying a "DateTime"-like datum that for some reason I need two views to specify.

Because the Javadocs deprecate all attempts to extract DateTime-field-type values from a `Date` instance, I thought to use the `Calendar` class to represent the user-selected combination of year,month,day,hour,minute,second.  I find that I often (but not always) can't decrement the hour or minute fields without simultaneously incrementing the day-of-month field.  Here's my event handler for the `DatePicker`:

```
        date = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.date);
        // h/t O'one https://stackoverflow.com/a/34952495/948073
        date.init(
                calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),
                new DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDateChanged(DatePicker datePicker, int y, int m, int d) {
                        System.out.println("onDateChanged(tp,"+y+","+m+","+d+")");
                        calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, y);
                        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, m);
                        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, d);
                        updateDropTime();
                    }
                }
        );
```

And the `TimePicker`.  Note the explicit backup-and-restore of the y/m/d fields in a vain attempt to stamp out suspected cross-contamination of y:m:d during h:m:s changes:

```
        private TimePicker time;
        dropTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dropTime);
        updateDropTime();
        time = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.tyme);


        time.setOnTimeChangedListener(new TimePicker.OnTimeChangedListener() {
            public void onTimeChanged(TimePicker tp, int h, int m) {
                System.out.println("onTimeChanged(tp,"+h+","+m+")");
                // Save state of y/m/d portion of calendar
                int y = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                int mo = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                int d = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                // Set h and m fields of calendar based on user input
                calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, h);
                calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, m);
                // Restore state of y/m/d fields
                calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, y);
                calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, mo);
                calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, d);
                // In theory y/m/d portion of datetime should be unchanged
                updateDropTime();
            }
        });
```

Both these event handlers call `updateDropTime()`, which looks like this:

```
private void updateDropTime() {
    String disp = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
    dropTime.setText(disp);
}
```

I suspect that something in the method chain leading to a value for `disp` is where the seemingly chaotic behavior takes place, seeing as I would think I've systematically stamped out any changes to date fields that could conceivably be side effects of changes to time fields.

Comment: Weird. Is the behavior deterministic? I mean, can you find an example calendar value and example `h` and `m` values that consistently produce the increment of the day-of-month field?

Comment: `Calendar` doesn’t always compute all fields when you make changes to its values. I was thinking that this might be related to the behavior you observe, but then again not since a call to `getTimeInMillis()` should compute the fields. See for example [Setting values of Java Calendar does not give expected date-time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20981963/setting-values-of-java-calendar-does-not-give-expected-date-time).

Comment: Can we rule out a concurrency issue? `Calendar` is not thread safe.

Comment: It may not be related to your issue: The `h` you get in `onTimeChanged` is hour of day on a 24 hour clock, so you want `calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, h);`.

Comment: Changed `HOUR` to `HOUR_OF_DAY` and so far I can spin the hour and minute spinners to my heart's content and the date fields are rock steady. Please post above comment as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This line is wrong:

```
            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, h);
```

Instead you want:

```
            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, h);
```

The `h` you get in `onTimeChanged()` is hour of day on a 24 hour clock. `Calendar.HOUR` means hour within AM or PM, that is, on a 12 hour clock.

How could this cause your issue? Example: Original time is 20:25 (or 8:25 PM if you like). User changes it to 13:28 (1:28 PM). You set `Calendar.HOUR` to 13. Since the original time was in PM and you don’t change this, you are effectively setting the time to 13:28 PM. This is nonsense, but `Calendar` doesn’t care, it just interprets it as `1:28` AM **the next day**. Setting the day doesn’t help, because at the time you do that, fields are not yet computed, so internally the time is still 13:28 PM on the correct day. Only when in the end you call `getTimeInMillis()`, are all the fields computed, the overflow detected and the date incremented.

### `Calendar` is default lenient

If you want to be notified about such an error (one that we all make from time to time), call `setLenient(false)` on your `Calendar` object after creating it. This will cause it not to accept out-of-range values like 13 for `HOUR`.

### java.time

If you don’t want to bother with the `Calendar` class at all, you’re certainly far from the first one, and there is a better and more programmer friendly alternative. The modern Java date and time API is built into Java 8 and later, and on Android you can have it in the [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), see [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project). I would suggest keeping the date in a `LocalDate` object and the time of day in a `LocalTime` so the user may update each independently with no risk of cross-contamination. Only in `updateDropTime()` would you combine the two into a `LocalDateTime` using `LocalDate.atTime()`, and then format it into your desired display format using a `DateTimeFormatter`.

```
public void onTimeChanged(TimePicker tp, int h, int m) {
    System.out.println("onTimeChanged(tp," + h + "," + m + ")");
    time = LocalTime.of(h, m);
    updateDropTime();
}
```

Updating could go like:

```
private void updateDropTime() {
    String disp = date.atTime(time)
            .format(DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime(FormatStyle.SHORT));
    dropTime.setText(disp);
}
```